# Website Causes Mobile Safari Crash (Replicable)

Tags: iphone, debugging, mobile, safari, crash

For some reason http://shirazraqs.com is causing mobile Safari to crash.  I've never seen anything like it and it's 100% replicatable so it's a bug on the site.

I've already tried ripping out all of the javascript but the bug persists even then.

Any other troubleshooting advice?  Better yet, has anyone heard of this?  I've been unable to find anyone experiencing similar problems via Google search :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with the new Google Fonts API.  Removing the Google Fonts CSS Stylesheet got rid of the problem... Head's up Google!